public keys block after update After updating from 2404 to 2410 i open software updater turn on other repository type in sudo apt update
 oldboy@oldboy:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for oldboy: 
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable/ubuntu/ mantic: -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
   mI0ETYF+BAEEAK1n4CPNzdG/rTNvteUkHOiSikl07GJl7jh8RjL4T2BA3g2J0M0g
   x20gOfc2Srbmg676cdf2kIzhfVPbjvWJnDYsFS1BOa0ZsKb0xN6lZzMU2lhmPMgF
   jJJk94BqeLlxr9wSqmOkR8X3yDtNWbZ+5xO1wDUP4GDZcCwesVsWfdXZABEBAAGw
   DAAAZ3BnAQAAAAAAALQlTGF1bmNocGFkIFBQQSBmb3IgRnJlZUNBRCBtYWludGFp
   bmVyc7AMAABncGcCAAAAAAAAiLgEEwECACIFAk2BfgQCGwMGCwkIBwMCBhUIAgkK
   CwQWAgMBAh4BAheAAAoJEABeroEZu1vKJLcD/jc5PThIN5JfHzXfSXk1q8NlJ4rH
   zziFex0wE6S6p12UDkPkO0I7ES+skTI/lOjlmvaYA65YycoO+wxQnB4qQq0eS4l3
   cc8ytmdsG0rcbEtlN7+xyWl8OIJmABsmobMC2kc25lfeSV3hQBo1zOch+hU8W8xn
   R/yGlzdQEjDGUHnVsAYAA2dwZwA=
   -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
    != -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
   mI0ETYF+BAEEAK1n4CPNzdG/rTNvteUkHOiSikl07GJl7jh8RjL4T2BA3g2J0M0g
   x20gOfc2Srbmg676cdf2kIzhfVPbjvWJnDYsFS1BOa0ZsKb0xN6lZzMU2lhmPMgF
   jJJk94BqeLlxr9wSqmOkR8X3yDtNWbZ+5xO1wDUP4GDZcCwesVsWfdXZABEBAAG0
   JUxhdW5jaHBhZCBQUEEgZm9yIEZyZWVDQUQgbWFpbnRhaW5lcnOIuAQTAQIAIgUC
   TYF+BAIbAwYLCQgHAwIGFQgCCQoLBBYCAwECHgECF4AACgkQAF6ugRm7W8oktwP+
   Nzk9OEg3kl8fNd9JeTWrw2UnisfPOIV7HTATpLqnXZQOQ+Q7QjsRL6yRMj+U6OWa
   9pgDrljJyg77DFCcHipCrR5LiXdxzzK2Z2wbStxsS2U3v7HJaXw4gmYAGyahswLa
   RzbmV95JXeFAGjXM5yH6FTxbzGdH/IaXN1ASMMZQedU=
   =3tnf
   -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
E: The list of sources could not be read.
update unable to open software updater


Step by step.
sudo add-apt-repository --list

Remove the PPA thats giving the error.
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable

then a bit of christmas cleaning:
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/freecad-maintainers-freecad-stable-*.list

then add it back with this.
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable

Should sort you out

Hi Thomas I try your method also try to used GUI to open software updater unable to openTypes: deb
URIs: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable/ubuntu/
Suites: mantic
Components: main
Signed-By: -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----Types: deb
URIs: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/trebelnik-stefina/synaptic/ubuntu/
Suites: mantic https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu/
Suites: mantic
Which I remove separately

when i run the cleanup command i get no such file or directory
